# how to change custom font inside listview using kotlin android

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I was looking for a lot on the Internet to solve my problem but I did not find a good solution.

**GOAL: How to change font in ListView?**

**XML layout code**

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/tvListDrinki"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="444dp"
android:background="@color/googleWhite"
android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

**List View “Ticket” Code**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_lista_drinkow"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivDrinkImage"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="50pt"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/martini" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="90pt"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Martini"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In My Kotlin Code I Have got a working standard adpater and listView elements
**Kotlin Code**

```
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {

        val drink= listOFDrinks[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.drinki_ticket,null)
        myView.tvName.text= drink.name!!
        myView.ivDrinkImage.setImageResource(drink.image!!)
        val face=Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "Fonts/Thin.ttf")
        myView.tvName.setTypeface(face)
        return myView

    }
```

Comment: you are trying to change font of the textview tvname right??

Comment: That's exactly what I mean

Comment: I have got a Error, the code does not recognize the command "getAssets()" and "assets," i update the post –

Comment: @YoungCodingStudent Check my answer for custom font setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android change ListView font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297087/android-change-listview-font)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in *Kotlin* you can do something like this.

```
myView.tvName.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
```

For Custom Font you can user ***ResourcesCompat.getFont*** as below.

```
val myCustomFont : Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.custom_font)
myView.tvName.typeface = myCustomFont
```

From *Assets* folder.

```
val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().assets, "font/custom_font.ttf")
myView.tvName.typeface = typeface
```

Comment: when i have Fonts in assets?

Answer (score 0):

**To change the font of textview**,write the following code in the adapter:

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/helloworld.ttf");
myView.tvName.setTypeface(face);
```

where **helloworld.ttf** is the font file stored in **asset folder of your project structure**.

Comment: I have got a Error, 
the code does not recognize the command "getAssets()" and "assets," i update the post

Comment: try face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/helloworld.ttf");

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font by

```
Typeface fType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Robotic.ttf"); 
tvname.setTypeface(fType);
```

For above to excute you need to create fonts under assets and keept .ttf file under fonts.

There is one more way create fonts folder under res directory and keep your ttf files inside.

and then in your xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Martini"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    **android:fontFamily="@font/Robotic.ttf"**
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: I have got a Error, the code does not recognize the command "getAssets()" and "assets," i update the post –

Comment: @YoungCodingStudent try fType = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Robotic.ttf");